# Ad Sense Management API Generate Report without OAuth?

Tags: oauth, adsense-api

I am creating an Application that displays the info of a Single Adsense account for all users. Do I still need to use OAuth for this? Because I do not need any user information, I simply want to show them the Information of one account. Is this possible? I want to do this:

> https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.3/reference/accounts/reports/generate#auth

Without using OAuth. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must use OAuth to access your AdSense Account via the Adsense API.

Check the examples, make one run and then substitute your own code.